# Error Could Not Implicit Value ToResponseMarshaller[SearchResponse]

Tags: json, scala, elasticsearch, akka

what i want to achieve are : create an API, which looking for into ElasticSearch. my programming language is Scala.

//myRoute.scala

```
val pencarianES =
  {
    post
    {
      path("cariES")
      {
        parameters("xQuery", "xNilai")
        {
          (yQuery, yNilai) =>
            val PR = new ProsesRekomendasi
            respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`application/json`)
            {
              complete
              {
                PR.ambilDariES(yQuery, yNilai)
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

//prosesRekomendasi.scala

```
class ProsesRekomendasi
{
  val ESM = new ESManager
  val CLT = ESM.client

  def ambilDariES(pQuery:String, pNilai:String) =
  {
    CLT.prepareSearch("app_lr_portal_01")
      .setTypes("lr01")
      .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery(s"$pQuery",s"$pNilai"))
      .execute()
      .actionGet()
  }
}
```

the error are :

```
could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller:
spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller[org.eleasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse]
PR.ambilDariES(yQuery, yNilai)
```

i was looking for at google, and founded 
[DefaultMarshallers missing with scala and spray-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664175/defaultmarshallers-missing-with-scala-and-spray-routing)

and then, im follow the instructions :

```
def ambilDariES(pQuery:String, pNilai:String)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext) =
  {
    CLT.prepareSearch("app_lr_portal_01")
      .setTypes("lr01")
      .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery(s"$pQuery",s"$pNilai"))
      .execute()
      .actionGet()
  }
```

finally, i get another error which are :

```
Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext, either import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global or use a custom one
                PR.ambilDariES(yQuery, yNilai)
```

any idea, how to deal with that? thanks for your help!

Comment: First, I'd recommend you you use English for your code examples as it will reduce cognitive burden of a person reading your code. For the first error - spray does not know how to marshal SearchResponse, you need to provide a marshaller explicitly if ElasticSearch API does not provide one. This documentation should give you some idea of next steps: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-httpx/marshalling/ For your last error - did you try to do what it asks you to do?

Comment: ok, pardon me @Tim. yes, i did. hehe

Comment: mr @Tim , i had similar problem like SunBright. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Although building RootJsonFormat for java classes is very tedious, here one example for one result. Just import in scope:

```
object SearchResultProtocol {

   implicit object SearchResulJsonFormatObject extends  RootJsonFormat[SearchResponse] {
     def read(e: JsValue) = null


/* {
 "_shards":{
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
 },
"hits":{
    "total" : 1,
    "hits" : [
        {
            "_index" : "twitter",
            "_type" : "tweet",
            "_id" : "1",
            "_source" : {
                "user" : "kimchy",
                "postDate" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
                "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}*/

 private def getHits(arr: Array[SearchHit]) : JsArray = { 
   JsArray(arr.map { x => marshallHit(x) }.toVector)
 }  


 private def marshallHit(hit: SearchHit) : JsValue = {
   JsObject(Map("_index" -> JsString(hit.index()),
                "_type" -> JsString(hit.getType),
                "_id" -> JsString(hit.getId),
                "source" -> JsString(hit.getSourceAsString)))
 }

 def write(sr: SearchResponse) = {
   JsObject(Map("_shards" -> 
               JsObject(Map("total" -> JsNumber(sr.totalShards()),
                            "successful" -> JsNumber(sr.getSuccessfulShards()),
                            "failed" -> JsNumber(sr.getFailedShards()))),
                 "hits" -> JsObject(Map("total" -> JsNumber(sr.getHits.totalHits()),
                                         "" -> getHits(sr.getHits.getHits)
                                           ))))

 }
}

}
```

Comment: hello @EmiCareOfCell44 , i get problem like SunBright. where is must, I put the code like your answer? thanks!

Comment: Yes, just import SearchResultProtocol._ and the compiler will find the serializer.

Comment: where i can find SearchResultProtocol._ ? @EmiCareOfCell44